# How to display cent sign when the string is passed to web form from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, character-encoding

I have a method in code-behind which returns a price as a string

```
public string GetPrice(){
    //some code
    price = "50&cent;";
    return price;
}
```

and in aspx page I use it like this:

```
<%: MoneyHelper.GetPrice() %>
```

It does not display cent sign, tried different coding of cent char but still it's a plain string. How to display it properly?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: I thought you needed &#37;

Comment: @BugFinder that's **per**cent :)

Comment: Ah.. I had no idea there was such a thing as a "cent" char, so assumed percent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try this code

 string cent = "50\u00A2";

Answer (score 1):

Because you already have the html encoded you need to use `<%= MoneyHelper.GetPrice() %>`

Or better yet use the unicode cent symbol on your method.

```
public string GetPrice(){
    //some code
    price = "50¢";
    return price;
}
```

Comment: .. because `<%:` [automatically HTML encodes the value](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2), while `<%= ` doesn't?

Comment: I'm guessing it's rendering as `50&amp;cent;`

Comment: It's rendering exactly as `50&cent;` the `<%: %>` is preserving the string passed by the code behind.

Comment: I tried using = and still it renders as a string.  This solved string cent = "50\u00A2";